# Use racadm to persistently set the first boot device to PXE

Tags: dell, drac

This is what I have been doing:

```
racadm -r <server> -u user -p password config -g cfgServerInfo -o cfgServerFirstBootDevice PXE
racadm -r <server> -u user -p password serveraction hardreset
```

This works great for the next boot, but after that it reverts to booting off of the hard drive. I have about 400 Dell rx720 machines that I would like to set this configuration on, so if I could automate this with a script it would save me a lot of time. Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer my own question, since I now know the answer. What needed to happen is to sent the cfgServerBootonce command, and set it to 0. So in this case, it would be:

```
racadm -r <server> -u user -p password config -g cfgServerInfo -o cfgServerFirstBootDevice PXE
racadm -r <server> -u user -p password config -g cfgServerInfo -o cfgServerBootOnce 0
racadm -r <server> -u user -p password serveraction powercycle
```

Now it works.